# Importing MMD animations causes a 'traceback' error

Tags: python, animation, error

I am having the most difficult time, and frankly I have no idea where to ask these kinds of questions, as no one has been able to help me yet..

Anyway, I'm trying to import MMD models and animations into blender. The models import just fine but when I try to import animations (vmd files) it gives this error and i have no idea what this means or what to do.

[image: error]

Comment: Some "_technobabble_" re unicode and the error. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html Basically there is a character in the file it does not know how to decode. Notice you are using blender 2.70.  Later versions use a later version of python which may have better unicode support and or an updated importer.  See in link can replace or ignore the character but that may produce strange results depending on the importance to the animation data within.